# Installtion error

Tags: php

Can anyone help me in installing PHP and MySQL. I am receiving an below error while installing.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.cli
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Error: `unable to locate the package.`

Comment: It appears that [you are using Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938387/ansible-istalation) which is not currently supported, and this is the reason why you are getting the error message: `Error: unable to locate the package.` If you installed a currently supported release like Ubuntu 16.04 this error would be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest that you use php7. Follow the instructions below:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

That will install php7. To get any module, you can search for it by:

```
sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

You can install the following modules to get you started:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json
```

To install mysql/mariadb:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y mariadb-server
```

Comment: thank you all for your kind reply.. however still I am facing same kind of errors..

Comment: Could you share the command you were running and the exact error you experienced. Its good to be verbose when requesting for help

Comment: I issued sudo apt-get install -y php7.1; reading package lists done, building dependency tree, reading state information .. done E: Unable to locate package php7.1, E:Couldn't find any package by regex pshp7.1